# ajax call in a post handler and ie trouble

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I need to make a post after a succes of another post, but in internet explorer this not works. Suggest?

Seems that the $.ajax call in lwaAjax_getrsp works with all browsers but not with ie.

```
$('#LoginWithAjax_Register form').submit(function(event){
    //Stop event, add loading pic...
    event.preventDefault();
    $('<div class="LoginWithAjax_Loading" id="LoginWithAjax_Loading"></div>').prependTo('#LoginWithAjax_Register');
    //Sort out url
    var url = $('#LoginWithAjax_Register form').attr('action');
    //Get POST data
    var postData = getPostData('#LoginWithAjax_Register form *[name]');
    $.post(url, postData, function(data){
        lwaAjax_getrsp(postData, data, 'LoginWithAjax_Register_Status', '#LoginWithAjax_Register' );            
    }, "json");
}); 

function lwaAjax_getrsp(posteddata, data, statusElement, prependTo ){
    $('#LoginWithAjax_Loading').remove();
    if( data.result === true || data.result === false ){
        if(data.result === true){
            //Login Successful
            var dataString_getrsp = 'name='+ posteddata['user_login'] + 
                                    '&email=' + posteddata['user_email'] +
                                    '&webform_id=' + 00001;
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: "http://www.getresponse.com/add_contact_webform.html",
                  data: dataString_getrsp,
                  success: function(data){
                      $('#result2').html("<h2>"+data+"</h2>");
                  }
            })

            if( $('#'+statusElement).length > 0 ){
                $('#'+statusElement).attr('class','confirm').html(data.message);
            }else{
                $('<span id="'+statusElement+'" class="confirm">'+data.message+'</span>').prependTo( prependTo );
            }
        }else{
            //Login Failed
            //If there already is an error element, replace text contents, otherwise create a new one and insert it
            if( $('#'+statusElement).length > 0 ){
                $('#'+statusElement).attr('class','invalid').html(data.error);
            }else{
                $('<span id="'+statusElement+'" class="invalid">'+data.error+'</span>').prependTo( prependTo );
            }

            var newrecoverylink = $('#custom_recovery_password').attr('href');
            $('#LoginWithAjax_Status a').attr('href',newrecoverylink);
        }
    }else{  
        //If there already is an error element, replace text contents, otherwise create a new one and insert it
        if( $('#'+statusElement).length > 0 ){
            $('#'+statusElement).attr('class','invalid').html('An error has occured. Please try again.');
        }else{
            $('<span id="'+statusElement+'" class="invalid">An error has occured. Please try again.</span>').prependTo( prependTo );
        }
    }
}
```

The problem seems isn't on the ajax call in the handler but, after a new analysis on the external domain, it's possible that i.e block ajax call to external domains?

How to work around? Thanks all!

This not work and alert2 do not display.

```
 $('#LoginWithAjax_Register form').submit(function(event){
    //Stop event, add loading pic...
    event.preventDefault();
    $('<div class="LoginWithAjax_Loading" id="LoginWithAjax_Loading"></div>').prependTo('#LoginWithAjax_Register');
    //Sort out url
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    //Get POST data
    var postData = getPostData('#LoginWithAjax_Register form *[name]');
    $.post(url, postData, function(data){
        lwaAjax_getrsp(postData, data, 'LoginWithAjax_Register_Status', '#LoginWithAjax_Register' );            
    }, "json"); 

    window.alert("1");

    $.post('http://www.getresponse.com/add_contact_webform.html', postData, function(data){         
    }, "jsonp");

    window.alert("2");  

});
```

This one works.

```
    $('#LoginWithAjax_Register form').submit(function(event){
    //Stop event, add loading pic...
    event.preventDefault();
    $('<div class="LoginWithAjax_Loading" id="LoginWithAjax_Loading"></div>').prependTo('#LoginWithAjax_Register');
    //Sort out url
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    //Get POST data
    var postData = getPostData('#LoginWithAjax_Register form *[name]');
    $.post(url, postData, function(data){
        lwaAjax_getrsp(postData, data, 'LoginWithAjax_Register_Status', '#LoginWithAjax_Register' );            
    }, "json"); 

    window.alert("1");

    $.post('/', postData, function(data){           
    }, "jsonp");

    window.alert("2");  

});
```

Comment: You're missing a `;` after your $.ajax(). Might that be the culprit?

Comment: just a note in your `submit()` function... `$('#LoginWithAjax_Register form').attr('action');` is the same as `$(this).attr('action');` also, you dont need your own function to get the post data. Instead of `getPostData()` which I assume is built by you, just use `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: with ";" the problem persist :( with i.e the next if is not made but with firefox it's all ok